# Share Text Document, or Photos with iCloud

Tags: xcode4.2, icloud, icloud-api

I would like to know if it is possible to upload a picture or a pdf Document to the `iCloud` and share it with others from there?

Just like on `Facebook`, I would like to Upload my Pictures and make it other people possible to watch it from there.

Does `iCloud` has such Sharing options?

Regards, Dennis

Answer (score 0):

iCloud is designed for sync and backup of documents not hosting of files. Also storing photos on your iCloud like that would get expensive quick as you would need to buy additional storage.
What you're talking about sounds like Photo stream in iPhoto. Pretty sure there is no API for it. 
If you are looking to build an app that shares photos into a stream I would look into one of the photo sharing sites like flickr, pretty sure they all have APIs for uploading photos.